# Substring into many field with iteration

Tags: sql, sql-server

My problem is: I have a `varchar`-type column (IDs) with string records like this: "123056; 96445; 123100; 45893; 201971" and  I want to divide them into the next fields:

```
 ID_1   | ID_2  | ID_3   | ID_4  | ID_5
 123056 | 96445 | 123100 | 45893 | 201971
```

Actually, I used this code:

```mssql
update MyTable  
set ID_1 = IDs
```

and then:

```mssql
update MYTable  
set ID_2 =    
SUBSTRING(ID_1, CHARINDEX (';', ID_1)+2, LEN(ID_1))    
where ID_1 like '%;%'

update MYTable   
set FRS_ID_1 =  
SUBSTRING(FRS_ID_1, 1, CHARINDEX (';', FRS_ID_1)-1)  
where ID_1 like '%;%'
```

The `ID_1 like '%;%'` is necessary because some fields contain only one number not a list. So I ran this code five times, manually updated the column name from `ID_1` to `ID_2` and etc. but it's not professional and  very slow.

How could I solve it with an iteration or in another way?

Thank you.

Comment: how often do you have to do this? cause if it is once in a blue moon, you could  use "text to columns" functionality of Excel. Export this table to Excel; go through "text to columns"; import back into sql db

Answer (score 0):

You should solve it by normalising your data.

ie: By having many rows with an ID in each record.

```
ID
123056 
96445 
123100 
45893 
201971
```

As for how to perform the split, a search engine will provide numerous options to [split a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql) by a character, using a function or a CTE.

Answer (score 0):

Split those values into a temp table or table variable as rows.

there's plenty of split functions samples out there...granted that your output will be like this:

```
ID
-------
123056
-------
96445
-------
ETC.
```

you can then do the following query:

```
Select 
     Min(Case rowid When 1 Then item End) id_1,
     Min(Case rowid When 2 Then item End) id_2,
     Min(Case rowid When 3 Then item End) id_3,
     Min(Case rowid When 4 Then item End) id_4,
     Min(Case rowid When 5 Then item End) id_5
INTO #TEMP_TABLE_WITH_COLUMNS
From #temp_table_with_IDs
```

this is, of course, assuming that you know upfront that you'll have 5 columns...